# issue with script execution in mobile application

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#sb").click(function() {
             $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   data: "{ UserName: '" + $('#UN').val() + "',Password:'"+$('#Psd').val()+"'}",
                   url: "DbLogic.aspx/User_Authentication",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function(data) {

                    if(data.d==1)
                    {
                         $.mobile.loadingMessage = "Please wait...";
                         $.mobile.pageLoading();
                         $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
                         document.location.href="DbLogic.aspx";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.location.href="#";
                    }
                   }  // end of success
                });  // end of ajax
             });    //end of click call  
           });      // end of jquery call
     </script>
```

In the above code I'm getting a error saying "**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method**". 
When executing `$.mobile.pageLoading();` error getting encounter. I have imported jQuery/jQuery Mobile javascript too.

Please tell me what I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `$.mobile.pageLoading();` function does not exists? See the API http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: ok i agree with you, this time i removed $.mobile.pageLoading(); statement. this time error points to $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method**

Comment: Can we see the source of one of your HTML pages?

Comment: My intention here is to display a loading message until new page gets load in mobile using jquery. 
If u have any sample please share it.

Answer (score 0):

> My intention here is to display a loading message until new page gets
>   load in mobile using jquery.

With the latest jQuery Mobile 1.1.0, they allow easy loading spinner customization :

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/config/loadingMessageTextVisible.html